# How to set specific colors lines in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot multiple lines using *ggplot2*. Below, there is an example of code.
I would like to plot the variables (class) 1 to 3 with grey color and mean with red color.

```
library('reshape2')
library('ggplot2')

times <- seq(100, 1000, by=100)
values <- data.frame(runif(10), runif(10), runif(10))
mean <- rowMeans(values)
df <- data.frame(times, values, mean)
names(df)=c("time", 1:3, 'means')

melted = melt(df, id.vars = "time", value.name="values",
              variable.name="class")
plot <- ggplot(data=melted, aes(x=time, y=values, group = class)) + geom_line() + labs(y= "Values", x = "Time")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(
  data=melted, 
  aes(x=time, y=values, color = class == "means", group = class)
) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(y= "Values", x = "Time") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "red"))
```